# How to delete similar text(text includes line number and different dates) in multiple lines of notepad++ without using thirdpart tool

Tags: notepad++

My input data in notepad++ is like below

```
Line  92135: D, [2022-09-01T09:53:48.290000 #14924] DEBUG -- :  select * from employees
Line  92137: D, [2022-09-02T11:53:48.296000 #14924] DEBUG -- :  select * from departments
Line  92138: D, [2022-09-03T08:53:48.297000 #14924] DEBUG -- :  select * from testreports
Line  92139: D, [2022-09-04T06:53:48.300000 #14924] DEBUG -- :  select * from dashboards
```

I want output data in notepad++ like below

```sql
select * from employees
select * from departments
select * from testreports
select * from dashboards
```

- Note
  file is in production environment so I can't include third party tools in notepad++

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+(?=\bselect\b)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
.+                  # 1 or more any character but newline
(?=\bselect\b)      # positive lookahead, make sure  we have "select" after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]